# Why are my subplots plotting only to the last ax?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

So in Spyder IPython and in Jupyter notebook, the following code is failing to create subplots:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mydict = {'a': [1,2,3,4], 'b':[2,3,4,5], 'c':[3,4,5,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3,1)
axes[0] = plt.plot(df.a)
axes[1] = plt.plot(df.b)
axes[2] = plt.plot(df.c)
plt.show(fig)
```

and it gives back the following plot:
[image]

this also happens when I copy-c copy-vd the example code from the matplotlib [webpage](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html)

what I would like is the three columns in the three different subplots to be plotted

Comment: `axes[0].plot(df.a)` and so on. Side note: I don't see that code snippet anywhere in the matplotlib docs.

Comment: thank you, what you suggested works, and I edited the question as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create your axes using `plt.subplots` you are using the object oriented approach in matplotlib. Then you have to call `plot()` on the axes object, so `axes[0].plot(df.a)`, not `plt.plot`.

What you are doing is a weird hybrid between the procedural and object oriented approach and you also overwrite the axes objects that you created when you write `axes[0] = plt.plot(...`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mydict = {'a': [1,2,3,4], 'b':[2,3,4,5], 'c':[3,4,5,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3,1)
axes[0].plot(df.a)
axes[1].plot(df.b)
axes[2].plot(df.c)
plt.show()
```